# How to define a constexpr lambda function

Tags: c++

I can assign a lambda function to a `constexpr` variable:

```
static constexpr auto f = []() {return 0;};
```

When I want to evaluate the function in a `constexpr`, the compiler complains that only constexpr functions can be used:

```
static auto constexpr i = f();
```

How can a define `constexpr` lambda?